# Gpsfake AttributeError: module object has no attribute 'get_bytes_stream'

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to execute gpsfake in Ubuntu VM. Unfortunately, a not self explained error happens.

If I use:

```
$ gpsfake -p -o -G -c 0.1 ~/x86/NMEA.txt
```

or also just:

```
$ gpsfake
```

The command returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gpsfake", line 33, in <module>
    bytesout = gps.get_bytes_stream(sys.stdout)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_bytes_stream'
```

gpsfake installed on Ubuntu 16.04, the name of the package in apt-get is python-gps and the version is = 3.15-2build1

I have tryed also uninstalling and reinstalling it using apt-get

Any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you install `gpsfake` as a package designed for your Ubuntu version? If not, which version of `gpsfake` did you install ? Where did you get it from? Which Ubuntu version do you use? Please [edit] your question to add information, don't answer in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem few days ago, if you are using an old version of Ubuntu (e.g. 16.4) and the version of your gpsd is manually updated. Then, when you have installed or update gpsfake via apt-get some file are updated to an old version. This cause an incompatibility due to old version are downloaded.
Try manually installing all the packets with a coherent version.